# date time paypal return

Tags: php, date, timestamp

PayPal Express Checkout return an array of response. Part of this response is this key:

#### [TIMESTAMP] = 2012-03-14T08:49:22Z

I am inserting the response into my database. However the timestamp seems to be not in valid format to fit in my column. The column details is this follows:

```
Column      |   Type    
------------------------
DateCreated |  datetime
```

How can I convert the returned timestamp into something fitting into my database?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime ('2012-03-14T08:49:22Z'));
```